# Export a raster from a WMS layer in QGIS Graphical Modeller

Tags: qgis, wms, qgis-processing, qgis-modeler

I would like to be able to export a section of a WMS to a georeferenced image using the graphical modeller.
I already have the extent setup for other things but I can't find an algorithm that will work.
I have tried "r.out.png" and "clip raster by extent" with no joy.

Comment: A WMS service returns a **picture** of the data you can not reliably extract meaningful information from it - if you require actual data you must use a WFS or WCS endpoint to fetch actual data.

Comment: A WMS can provide pictures of lots of different types of data. In this case its an aerial image and there are plenty of ways to get a clipped extent at a certain resolution but I can't find one that works inside the modeller.

Comment: that's because it is still a picture not a data source, use a WCS which is designed for this

Comment: No WCS available

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export a rendering of the WMS using the **Convert map to raster** algorithm which allows the specification of resolution, extent and layers to include.